# WildFly 8 Where Are Compiled JSP?

Tags: jsp, jboss, wildfly

We are migrating from JBoss AS7 to Wildfly 8. In JB7 the compiled JSPs are in standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host. But I can't find them in Wildfly. Does anyone know where they are? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

compiled JSP files are into **standalone/tmp/[application-name].war/org/apache/jsp**. 
For example, if you deployed an application named test.war, you will find the compiled JSP into C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\test.war\org\apache\jsp (Assuming you have installed WildFly on C:)